# Outllok mail account with same mail address

Tags: outlook, office365

Due to server change, I need to make another account in Outlook so that it can take over when the new server is up and running.
I have created the new email address on the new server, but when I try to create it in outlook, I can't make an account with the same email address despite that the servers for in and out are different from the current server.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that is an Exchange account, you won't have much luck - autodiscover will redirect to the active server. You cannot explicitly specify the serve parameters.

Comment: It is iMap og POP3 accounts

Comment: Just name the accounts differently - if you want the old account interface, add the account from Control Panel | Mail instead of Outlook itself.